# Programmatically create WSDL from metadata

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wsdl

How can I override the way ASP.NET creates a WSDL file for my Web Serive from my `WebMethod`s' metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark your class with the attribute `[XmlSchemaProvider]` as shown [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/XmlSchemaProvider.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control this very much. You can control the shape of the XML request and response by using attributes like `[XmlElementAttribute]`. You can control the name and namespace of the request and response with the `[WebMethod]` attribute.

What are you trying to accomplish?